# flextable and officedown error: read_docx only support docx files

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

flextable and officedown produces an error: read_docx only support docx files appears in minimial attempt at using officedown. I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650843/rmarkdown-package-flextable-fails-immediately-with-read-docx-only-support-docx), but my file path has no spaces so that does not appear to be the issue.

```
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Your Name"
title: "officedown template"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    mapstyles:
      Normal: ['First Paragraph']
---

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.cap = TRUE)
library(officedown)
library(officer)
library(flextable)

fp <- fp_par(
  text.align = "center", 
  padding.bottom = 20, padding.top = 120, 
  border.bottom = fp_border())

ft <- fp_text(shading.color='#EFEFEF', bold = TRUE)

flextable(mtcars)
```

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.4.0.2        flextable_0.6.0.002  officer_0.3.14       officedown_0.2.1.001

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] xfun_0.17         remotes_2.1.1     testthat_2.3.2    miniUI_0.1.1.1    htmltools_0.5.0  
 [6] usethis_1.6.1     yaml_2.2.1        base64enc_0.1-3   rlang_0.4.7       pkgbuild_1.0.8   
[11] later_1.1.0.1     glue_1.4.2        withr_2.2.0       gdtools_0.2.2     sessioninfo_1.1.1
[16] uuid_0.1-4        zip_2.1.1         devtools_2.3.0    memoise_1.1.0     evaluate_0.14    
[21] knitr_1.30        callr_3.4.3       fastmap_1.0.1     httpuv_1.5.4      ps_1.3.3         
[26] fansi_0.4.1       Rcpp_1.0.5        xtable_1.8-4      promises_1.1.1    backports_1.1.7  
[31] desc_1.2.0        pkgload_1.1.0     jsonlite_1.7.1    mime_0.9          systemfonts_0.3.2
[36] fs_1.4.1          digest_0.6.25     processx_3.4.2    rprojroot_1.3-2   here_0.1         
[41] cli_2.0.2         tools_4.0.2       magrittr_1.5      whisker_0.4       crayon_1.3.4     
[46] ellipsis_0.3.1    data.table_1.12.8 xml2_1.3.2        prettyunits_1.1.1 rvg_0.2.5        
[51] reprex_0.3.0      assertthat_0.2.1  rmarkdown_2.4     rstudioapi_0.11   R6_2.4.1         
[56] compiler_4.0.2
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce your error. Your Rmd renders fine on my machine. I tried both the CRAN versions of flextable and officedown as well as the development versions which you are using.

Comment: This is the 3rd time someone report that, I am still not able to identify the issue (and I'd like to be able to reproduce it so that I can solve it). Could you also add information about the path of your rmd file and also `.libPaths()`. This may help...

Comment: Hi David, The path of the RMD file is: C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Check\test_officdown_v2.Rmd

`.libPaths()` returned "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library"

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jessica and David Gohel,

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650843/rmarkdown-package-flextable-fails-immediately-with-read-docx-only-support-docx) that had the same error about `read_docx` when using `flextable`. Based on the great effort by Mike M, the problem is most possibly from the **filepath**!

I have fixed my problem because I finally found a space in my username so the filepath of templated generated by officedown will be copied to `C:\Users\Myfirstname Mygivenname\AppData\something_else`. Then in terminal it will be `C:\Users\Myfirstname~Mygivenname\AppData\something_else` and get wrong. This is may be the question for Windows users as I have tried the same thing on my Mac and it works.

So make sure that your username (or the entire filepath) **does not have any space**!

Thanks David for `officedown` package and the work by Mike M.